# Calculations on user input in Entry box Python tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, spyder, tkinter-entry

I just have a quick question regarding calculations from a user input via the Entry Box. I'm confused as to why the calculation isn't being performed in the "def concentration" function labelled "CCalc". I imagine the error is coming from the code being unable to get the user input, "tbschk", from the previous function. Is there something else I need to look into to figure how to do this correctly?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Label, Button, Entry

#multiply total brain by 1000ul
def tbscalc():
    Bchk=float(BNum.get())
    BCalc = (Bchk*1000)
    tbsCalc["text"]=str(BCalc)

#divide concentration by total TBSul
def concentration():
    Cchk=float(Conc.get())
    tbschk=float(tbsCalc.get())
    CCalc=(tbschk/Cchk)
    PCalc["text"]=str(CCalc)

window=tk.Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")

#Using total brain to calculate TBS
BLabel=Label(window, text="Enter number of brains")
tbsLabel=Label(window, text="Amount of TBS needed in ul")
tbsCalc=Label(window)
BNum=Entry(window)
BTBSbtn=Button(window, text="Calculate", command=tbscalc)

#Using concentration to calculate total primary
CLabel=Label(window, text="Enter primary concentration")
PLabel=Label(window, text="This is how much primary antibody you need")
PCalc=Label(window)
Conc=Entry(window)
TPbtn=Button(window, text="Calculate", command=concentration)

#Locations
BLabel.grid(row=0 ,column=0)
BNum.grid(row=0 ,column=1)
tbsLabel.grid(row=1 ,column=0)
tbsCalc.grid(row=1 ,column=1)
BTBSbtn.grid(row=2 ,column=0)
CLabel.grid(row=3, column=0)
Conc.grid(row=3, column=1)
PLabel.grid(row=4, column=0)
PCalc.grid(row=4, column=1)
TPbtn.grid(row=5, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

I get the error message:

> Exception in Tkinter callback
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Users\Kevin\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1699, in **call**
>           return self.func(*args)
>         File "C:/Users/Kevin/Desktop/Python/IHCprotocol.py", line 13, in concentration
>           tbschk=float(tbsCalc.get())
>       AttributeError: 'Label' object has no attribute 'get'

The error it's referring to

```
class CallWrapper:
    """Internal class. Stores function to call when some user
    defined Tcl function is called e.g. after an event occurred."""
    def __init__(self, func, subst, widget):
        """Store FUNC, SUBST and WIDGET as members."""
        self.func = func
        self.subst = subst
        self.widget = widget
    def __call__(self, *args):
        """Apply first function SUBST to arguments, than FUNC."""
        try:
            if self.subst:
                args = self.subst(*args)
            return self.func(*args)
        except SystemExit:
            raise
        except:
            self.widget._report_exception()
```

Comment: What do you mean "the calculation isn't performed"? Is that modern speak for "it throws an exception"? If so, you should include the error message and the complete traceback in your question.

Comment: Looks like it's time to take a nap...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot `get` the value which you are displaying as `label` that is what the error is telling you, to resolve that i created `entry widget` named `e1` and didn't position in the window so that i can get the value in it.You window looks same but now able get the result to display.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Label, Button, Entry

#multiply total brain by 1000ul

def tbscalc():
    Bchk=float(BNum.get())
    BCalc = (Bchk*1000)
    tbsCalc["text"]=str(BCalc)
    e1.insert(0, BCalc) # this receiving the answer in the so that i can be return

#divide concentration by total TBSul
def concentration():
    Cchk=float(Conc.get())
   # tbschk=float(tbsCalc.get())
    tbschk = float(e1.get()) # this getting the value in the entry widget
    CCalc=(tbschk/Cchk)
    PCalc["text"]=str(CCalc)


window=tk.Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")

#Using total brain to calculate TBS
BLabel=Label(window, text="Enter number of brains")
tbsLabel=Label(window, text="Amount of TBS needed in ul")
tbsCalc=Label(window)
BNum=Entry(window)
BTBSbtn=Button(window, text="Calculate", command=tbscalc)

#Using concentration to calculate total primary
CLabel=Label(window, text="Enter primary concentration")
PLabel=Label(window, text="This is how much primary antibody you need")
PCalc=Label(window)
Conc=Entry(window)
TPbtn=Button(window, text="Calculate", command=concentration)

e1 = Entry(window) # this new entry i created but didn't position
#e1.grid(row=5, column=30)

#Locations
BLabel.grid(row=0 ,column=0)
BNum.grid(row=0 ,column=1)
tbsLabel.grid(row=1 ,column=0)
tbsCalc.grid(row=1 ,column=1)
BTBSbtn.grid(row=2 ,column=0)
CLabel.grid(row=3, column=0)
Conc.grid(row=3, column=1)
PLabel.grid(row=4, column=0)
PCalc.grid(row=4, column=1)
TPbtn.grid(row=5, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```